# Returning the Cricket Kit

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, geography, steganography, anagram

It was approaching the Easter Holidays at **Farthingbottom School** and Class 5M had been asked to clean out the cricket pavilion, ready for the start of the season next term.

Under one of the benches in the "Away" changing room they came across an expensive-looking cricket bag with a number of pads and a several bats in it.

"I think we need to get this bag back to the rightful owner", said Felix, "or at least to the right building."
"Are there any clues who it might belong to?" asked Portia
"There's this," said Randolph, pulling a battered UK atlas out of the bag.
As he pulled it out, a single sheet of paper fell from between the pages.

One side of the paper looked a bit like this:[image]

And the other side looked like this:[image]

"These look bowling scoresheets" said Portia.
"Yes, but there's something a bit odd about them - there's not a single extra in any of the overs" replied Felix.

"Look here", said Randolph, "if you hold it up to the light, there's a watermark."
True enough, the outline of a bird could be seen, along with the letters **P S C F**
"I'm not sure the watermark will help us find what we're looking for", said Portia, "but it might just confirm that we've got the right place."

"How do we know which side of the paper to look at first?", said Randolph.
"Let's just hope it's obvious if we get things in the wrong order" answered Felix.

**Question:** Can you help Class 5M work out where to send the cricket bag?

Comment: Does solving this require knowledge of cricket? (I know nothing about cricket.)

Comment: @dpwilson No, this puzzle could be solved by someone with no knowledge of cricket whatsoever.

Comment: The dots on the cards look alot like braille...

Comment: Is there meant to not be any symbol next to the 6 on the top row?

Comment: @Deusovi - Well spotted. There should be a dot there

Comment: @Keir - If this translates to anything in braille, it is purely coincidental.

Comment: Ron Ghints could be "Wrong Hints" meaning we could exclude second set.

Comment: There's an extra box for the second set on the back of the page?  Is this normal in cricket?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: It's possible for one "innings" (that each of the 4 sets represents) to have more "overs" (boxes) than another.

Comment: Thanks,  And what does "there's not a single extra in any of the overs" mean?

Comment: An over consists of six legal "deliveries", but there can be illegal ones which count as "extras".  It's rare not to have one in so many overs.  ...  That's the literal meaning, it might be a wordplay.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The bag belongs to the:

> Cirencester Cricket Club

KeyboardWielder pointed out that:

> The names are anagrams of "Eastings" and "Northings"

Based on the work of LeppyR64, you need to:

> Sum up the runs in each box, and stop at a W.  You get 12 pairs of coordinates:
>
>  Eastings Northings
>  487010 200880
>  401660 378630
>  359486 298349
>  439290 458940
>  508866 336243
>  595530 235680
>
>  Eastings Northings
>  347849 1016464
>  428930 272180
>  465241 348546
>  388348 418002
>  262300 274820
>  324340 305929

Each of those maps to a:

> Town/village with a hidden number as part of its name:
>
>  Pres**two**od
>  Fer**nil**ee
>  Stretton Wes**two**od
>  C**one**ythorpe
>  **Three**kingham
>  H**one**y Tye
>
>  Bal**four**
>  Ke**nil**worth
>  Epperst**one**
>  Whi**two**rth
>  Lla**nil**ar
>  L**eight**on

Taking those gives us a new:

> Pair of coordinates: 202131 and 401208

And mapping those takes us to:

> The [Cirencester Cricket Club](http://gridreferencefinder.com/?gr=SP0120802131%7C401208_s__c__s_202131%7C1&t=401208%20%2C%20202131&v=h)

P S C F stands for:

> Prorsum semper corinium floret, the latin motto of the Cirencester Cricket Club, which translates perhaps to Ever Forward, Corinium Flourishes (Corinium being the Roman name for the town).

Which can be found on the club flag, along with the watermark:

> [image: Cirencester flag]

Comment: Can you explain the bird watermark and "P S C F"?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Gave it a shot.

Comment: Excellent! The children are delighted. Gave LeppyR64 +1 for his contribution too.

Comment: As did I! Couldn't have done it without him.

Comment: Very good!  Thanks for finishing it off.  I think what I was tripping on was the "nils".  I was seeing the numbers but they weren't clicking because I was missing nil.  Good work!

Answer (score 8):

Partial:

> Following the tracks of the others. By summing up the runs in the boxes (all less than 10) and then stopping at the wicket (w) yields the following pairs:

Sheet1:

> Eastings   Northings
>    487010 200880
>     401660    378630
>     359486    298349
>     439290    458940
>     508866    336243
>     595530    235680

Sheet2

> Eastings  Northings
>     347849    1016464
>     428930    272180
>     465241    348546
>     388348    418002
>     262300    274820
>     324340    305929

Analysis:

> Using OSGB36 references makes this look a lot better.

[UK Map](http://gridreferencefinder.com/?gr=SP8701000880%7C487010_s__c__s_200880%7C1,SK0166078630%7C401660_s__c__s_378630%7C1,SO5948698349%7C359486_s__c__s_298349%7C1,SE3929058940%7C439290_s__c__s_458940%7C1,TF0886636243%7C508866_s__c__s_336243%7C1,TL9553035680%7C595530_s__c__s_235680%7C1,HY4784916464%7C347849_s__c__s_1016464%7C1,SP2893072180%7C428930_s__c__s_272180%7C1,SK6524148546%7C465241_s__c__s_348546%7C1,SD8834818002%7C388348_s__c__s_418002%7C1,SN6230074820%7C262300_s__c__s_274820%7C1,SJ2434005929%7C324340_s__c__s_305929%7C1&v=h)

Comment: The children think you are definitely onto something here.

Comment: Randolph says "Maybe there's some system other than UTM for referencing locations in the UK with Easting / Northing coordinates?"

Comment: Portia points out that there are little dots in the UK atlas that match the pins on your latest map.

Comment: @GordonK Yay! I was pretty certain there would be but confirmation is a good thing :)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer. Not sure if its right or not:

> Using the Easting and Northing coordinate system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easting_and_northing
>  as noted by @Zandar, the names are anagrams for Eastings and Northings
>
>  Taking the sum of all the numbers in an "over" (the sum is always < 10) as a digit of the coordinates : XX degrees, XX', XX" and assuming the `W` represents the start/end of each of the coordinate
>  You get the following :
>
>  48 degrees 70' 10" Easting, 20 degrees 8' 80" Northing
>
>  40 degrees 16' 60" Easting, 37 degrees 86' 30" Northing
>
>  35 degrees 94' 86" Easting, 29 degrees 83' 49" Northing

Comment: There could be something in this, though you don't get more than 60 minutes in a degree or more than 60 degrees in a second.

Answer (score 3):

Partial analysis:

The team names [corrected with help from @Zandar]:

> The anagrams are "Eastings" and "Northings"

The scores:

> = runs for wickets in overs
>  = (sum of numbers) for (count of 'W's) in (number of boxes)
>  Commonly written as runs/wickets (overs)
>
>   Eastings: 159/6 (36)
>   Northings: 155/6 (36)
>   Eastings: 146/6 (36)
>   Northings: 137/6 (37)
>  *(If I counted right)*

The solution probably:

> Uses these numbers as distances, but I'm not sure of the reference and unit.  Possibly UTM zone 5M.

Comment: See comment above:  
 
[At sign] dpwilson No, this puzzle could be solved by someone with no knowledge of cricket whatsoever. – Gordon K Mar 21 at 18:23

Comment: But I like this attempt.

Comment: The anagrams are more likely "eastings" and "northings".

Comment: @Zandar: I though of that too, but it didn't make sense till I looked at Wikipedia just now.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: Yes, I saw that comment; but since the sums and counts might be required, even if you don't need to know what they represent, I thought I'd provide them to save others the trouble...  ;)

Comment: Could also be Northings and Eastings  (Which confirms the coordinate idea)

Comment: I made an edit - last one for the day.  Feel free to use it to develop your own answer.

Comment: I've got Port of Spain Cricket field in Trinidad at 10°40'02.5"N 61°31'25.3"W    The Symbol for Trinidad is a red ibis, which could mean something for the watermark.  But the coordinates can't be squeezed into the puzzle.

Comment: @chriscudmore The cricket bag doesn't look like it's ever been on a plane. There are no baggage stickers on it.

Comment: The bag could have been on a plane. It could be carry-on baggage, therefore not requiring stickers. Or maybe the bag is too big for carry-on?

Comment: @mestackoverflow The atlas is a UK atlas too, so the students are pretty sure that they don't have to send the bag abroad.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial attempt**

> I'm not familiar with neither cricket nor bowling scoring, but I noticed that the W marked boxes follow a quite strict pattern on two levels:
>  - they appear in every sixth box (with the only exception being the 4th panel, where there is an extra first box) - maybe this suggests, that the sides are in reversed order?;
>  - the position of the W inside the box is also quite regular in the 1st panel: goes from left to right, then next row, cyclically, only exception in the last box.